# Android RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

Trying to learn how to develop an android app and running into what seems like a basic problem but having issues understanding how to move forward.
I have a `RecyclerView` that displays the API list correctly and I get how to do that. What I want to do next is if the user clicks the item (passing the device ID) it will go into the detail of the item passing a different API call (different URL). What I am not understanding is how to move into the details after the click.

I am debugging the code and have the click's logging correctly with the device ID correctly but not sure where to go from here. Do I somehow "refresh" the RecyclerView and display the new data or do I create a new activity and display the results there?

List of Devices API

```
[
    {
        "id": "65",
        "name": "Switch - Kitchen",
        "label": "Switch - Kitchen"
    },
    {
        "id": "98",
        "name": "Location Sensor - 1",
        "label": "Location Sensor - 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "99",
        "name": "Location Sensor - 2",
        "label": "Location Sensor - 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "136",
        "name": "Switch - Bedroom",
        "label": "Switch - Bedroom"
    },
    {
        "id": "161",
        "name": "Location Sensor - 3",
        "label": "Location Sensor - 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "193",
        "name": "Switch - Family Room",
        "label": "Switch - Family Room"
    }
]
```

Device Details API

```
{
    "id": "65",
    "name": "Switch - Kitchen",
    "label": "Switch - Kitchen",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "switch",
            "currentValue": "off",
            "dataType": "ENUM",
            "values": [
                "on",
                "off"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "capabilities": [
        "Switch",
        {
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "switch",
                    "dataType": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "Configuration",
        "Refresh",
        "Actuator"
    ],
    "commands": [
        "configure",
        "flash",
        "off",
        "on",
        "refresh",
        "refresh"
    ]
}
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //Global Variable for Device ID//
    class vdeviceID: Application() {
        companion object{
            var globalDeviceID = 0
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rv__list_posts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //Debugging URL//
        val interceptor : HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }

        val client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            this.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }.build()
        //Debugging URL//

        //Base of API Call//

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/apps/api/109/")
            .client(client)
            .build()
        //Base of API Call//


    //Build List of Devices//
        val postsApi = retrofit.create(INetworkAPI::class.java)
        var response = postsApi.getAllPosts(access_token = "xxxxxxx")

        //Displaying List//
        response.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(IoScheduler()).subscribe {
            rv__list_posts.adapter = PostItemAdapter(it, this)
        }
```

API Call

```
interface INetworkAPI {
    @GET("devices")
    fun getAllPosts(@Query("access_token") access_token: String): Observable<List<DevicesList>>

}
```

Item Adapter

```
class PostItemAdapter(private val postList: List<DevicesList>, private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item_layout, parent, false)


        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val globalDeviceID = this.postList[position].id
        holder.itemView.txtPostID.text = this.postList[position].id
        holder.itemView.txtPostName.text = this.postList[position].name
        holder.itemView.txtPostLabel.text = this.postList[position].label
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                v -> Log.d("TAG", globalDeviceID)
        }
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Want to display this after onclick

```
//Specific Devices//
        val postsDetailsApi = retrofit.create(INetworkAPIDetails::class.java)
        var responseDetails = postsDetailsApi.getAllDetails(access_token = "xxxxxxx")
        //Displaying List//
        responseDetails.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(IoScheduler()).subscribe {
            rv__list_posts.adapter = PostItemDetailsAdapter(it, this)
        }
```

Specific Device API

```
interface INetworkAPIDetails {
    @GET("devices/")
    fun getAllDetails(@Query("access_token") access_token: String): Observable<List<DeviceDetails>>
    fun getAllDetailsAttr(): Observable<List<Attribute>>
}
```

Specific Device Interface

```
class PostItemDetailsAdapter(private val postdetailsList: List<Attribute>, private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostItemDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item_details,
                parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postdetailsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        //holder.itemView.txtPostID.text = this.postdetailsList[position].id
        holder.itemView.txtPostName.text = this.postdetailsList[position].name
        holder.itemView.txtPostCurrent.text = this.postdetailsList[position].currentValue
        holder.itemView.txtPostDataType.text = this.postdetailsList[position].dataType
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Comment: It's normal to use a separate activity or fragment to show the detail page. You can call your specific API from your detail activity/fragment

Comment: What would be the best method to do that? Duplicate the activity_main into a separate activity and call it from the onclick listener?

Comment: Why do you want to copy the main_activity. Create a new layout you need to show the corresponding details and call your api from your onCreate()

Comment: the Capabilities array can contain both strings and objects? O_O? Who wrote this API?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `RecyclerView` click events in your adapter(in BindViewHolder or YourViewHolder). I prefer to open new activity and show details in there

```
class PostItemDetailsAdapter(private val postdetailsList: List<Attribute>, private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostItemDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item_details,
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postdetailsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            //do sth in here
        }

        //holder.itemView.txtPostID.text = this.postdetailsList[position].id
        holder.itemView.txtPostName.text = this.postdetailsList[position].name
        holder.itemView.txtPostCurrent.text = this.postdetailsList[position].currentValue
        holder.itemView.txtPostDataType.text = this.postdetailsList[position].dataType
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Adapter :

```
class PostItemDetailsAdapter(private val postdetailsList: List<Attribute>, private val context: Context, val action: View.OnClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostItemDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item_details,
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postdetailsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.(/*Pass your itemview name).setOnClickListener({it->
            /*Put log for that id */
            action.onClick(it)
        })

        //holder.itemView.txtPostID.text = this.postdetailsList[position].id
        holder.itemView.txtPostName.text = this.postdetailsList[position].name
        holder.itemView.txtPostCurrent.text = this.postdetailsList[position].currentValue
        holder.itemView.txtPostDataType.text = this.postdetailsList[position].dataType
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Now put those things in your Activity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter: PostItemDetailsAdapter
    lateinit var action: View.OnClickListener
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            rv__list_posts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            action = View.OnClickListener {
               //Things you want to do it in your On Click you can log 
            }
    }
}
```

Just Pass the parameter values to adapter :

```
rv__list_posts.adapter = PostItemDetailsAdapter(it, this, action)
```

Hope it will work for you. If there is any problem tell ill check.

Comment: I did like you suggested and nothing happens when I click an item. I put a log item in the onclicklistener in the mainactivity and when I click no logs come through. If I put the onclicklistener in the first adapter, it returns values but it creates an error using your suggestion on the main activity. The postitemadapter is displayed first as soon as the app loads. I want to take the Id from the item selected in that list, pass it to the postitemdetailsadapater and display the data for the details.

Comment: please try changes and tell me your log now

Comment: I think this was put in the wrong spot because I am trying to click the button from the initial adapter, which is postitemadapter. I moved this code to that adapter and now getting this error on main activity ``` rv__list_posts.adapter = PostItemAdapter(it, this)``` no value passed for parameter action

Comment: on which itemview you want to click tell me ill provide full code of yours.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just had to pass the "action" in the argument. Its going to the next activity now, just have to mess with the API call now. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: @user1722885 please accept the answer if it worked for you and just make changes in it